# How to reference and dynamically display documents based off of input on a form

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, form

I'm using Sharepoint 2013. 
I'd like users to be able to select a series of drop down boxes of categories and have a list of documents automatically filter based off those choices. I'd also like to make it so users do not have to leave a page to perform this.

As of now I have a form with javascript responding to changes like so:

```
<select id="testSelect">
    <option>Select Item</option>
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option>Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>    
</select>


<script>
    $('#testSelect').change(function() {
      var val = $("#testSelect option:selected").text();
      alert(val);
    });
</script>
```

But I'm not sure of a method to reference to documents based on options.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013